# Randomly display images using jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, random

You have a set of images:

```
<ul class="thumb">
    <li><a href="#">
        <img src="images/att.jpg" title="Store AT&T" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
        <img src="images/images%20(10).jpg" title="Store Wiki" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
        <img src="images/nintendo.jpg" title="Store Nintendo" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
        <img src="images/images%20(11).jpg" title="Store WorldConference" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
        <img src="images/images%20(13).jpg" title="Store GoeSystem" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
        <img src="images/images%20(14).jpg" title="Store Something" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
        <img src="images/images%20(3).jpg" title="Store Lego" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
        <img src="images/images%20(4).jpg" title="Store Something" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
        <img src="images/images%20(3).jpg" title="Store Lego" alt="" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to `.fadeIn()` images randomly. I tried the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012264/jquery-randomly-fadein-images), but my `.children().length` is always 0 for some reason.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Make sure you are waiting for the DOM to load before executing that script.  The children have to render before jQuery recognizes them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update of your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jKtfZ/44/

In a selector the `>` character means direct child.  Therefore, `#container > img` will return nothing.  The `img` tags are not direct children of `#container`.

EDIT: also, not sure why you were adding 3 when creating your random number

EDIT2:  similarly, `$('#container').children().length;` will give you the direct children of `#container`, that is the `<li>` elements, not the `img`.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, was working late through the night, so guess I lost track of what I was doing, not sure why I added the 3!

Answer (score 0):

What selector do you use before `.children().length`? You should search for your class name, since you have not given that element an id:

```
$(".thumb").children().length
```

Or assign an id to it:

```
<ul class="thumb" id="container">
    <li><a href="#">
        <img src="images/att.jpg" title="Store AT&T" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
        <img src="images/images%20(10).jpg" title="Store Wiki" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
        <img src="images/nintendo.jpg" title="Store Nintendo" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
        <img src="images/images%20(11).jpg" title="Store WorldConference" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
        <img src="images/images%20(13).jpg" title="Store GoeSystem" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
        <img src="images/images%20(14).jpg" title="Store Something" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
        <img src="images/images%20(3).jpg" title="Store Lego" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
        <img src="images/images%20(4).jpg" title="Store Something" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
        <img src="images/images%20(3).jpg" title="Store Lego" alt="" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

Then you can use the id selector:

```
$("#container").children().length
```